# Rendered Height and Client Height aren't the same

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a react application which contains a react component of publication cards. They represent a publication that has a title, some authors, a summary, date, and some other fields. I want each of the elements to have the same card size and each of the elements within the card to line up so the title sections are all the same height as the tallest title, the authors are the same height as the tallest of the authors and so on.

To do this, I have have an inner div that contains the content shouldn't change it's height and and outer div that I set to the highest clientHeight of all inner div elements.

I have a resize function that works, however only for when you drag and move the browser by resizing the window. When I click the maximize, restore, or snap the browser to the screen it ignores the height of the inner div and sets it to weird values. Ie, the rendered size of the content will be 85px in the chrome debugger, however clientWidth if I trace that value before I set it shows all of them for each of the inner divs as like 28 and so the outer div is being set to that value.

```
    render() {
        return (
            <PubContainer>
                <TitleSection                        
                    style={{ height: this.state.pubTitleHeight }}>
                        <InnerDiv className="innerPubTitleDiv">
                            {this.props.publicationData.header}                            
                            <SubtitleSection>
                                {this.props.publicationData.subtitle}
                            </SubtitleSection>       
                        </InnerDiv>
                </TitleSection>
            </PubContainer>
        );
    }
```

SubtitleSection is a div and InnerDiv is the container that should have its height set to whatever is the value within. Here the rest of the code, along with the resize function.

```
     componentDidUpdate() {        
        this.updatePublicationCardSizes();        
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this._isMounted = true;

        this.updatePublicationCardSizes();
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.updatePublicationCardSizes.bind(this));
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this._isMounted = false;
        window.removeEventListener('resize', this.updatePublicationCardSizes.bind(this));
    }

    updatePublicationCardSizes() {        
        this.setContainerHeightByClassName('innerPubTitleDiv', 'pubTitleHeight');
    }

    setContainerHeightByClassName(innerDivClassName, stateName) {
        var classNameList = document.getElementsByClassName(innerDivClassName);

        if (classNameList != undefined) {
            var maxHeight = 0;

            for (var index = 0; index < classNameList.length; index++) {
                var divHeight = classNameList[index].clientHeight;

                if (maxHeight < divHeight) {
                    maxHeight = divHeight;
                }
            }

            if (this._isMounted) {
                if (maxHeight > 0) {
                    if (this.state[stateName] != maxHeight) {                        
                    this.setState({
                        [stateName]: maxHeight
                    });
                }
                } else {
                    if (this.state[stateName] != '100%'){
                        this.setState({
                            [stateName]: '100%'
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I've verified that resize is being called on all changes to the browser (drag, snap, restore, max, min). And again, the normal resizing by dragging the browser to change width does update and resize it correctly, it's only when I click the maximize button for example do I get the weird values. I'm trying to find out why just those cases don't work and how to make them work.

EDIT

I've refactored my code to use hooks, but I'm still getting the same issue when I click maximize/restore. Apparently the inner div clientHeight is still being calculated from a pre-render size, instead of setting it after the resize event has finished and rendered. Any ideas?

```
function PublicationCard(props) {

    const [pubTitleHeight, setTitleHeight] = useState('100%');

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        updatePublicationCardSizes();
        window.addEventListener("resize", updatePublicationCardSizes);

        return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", updatePublicationCardSizes);
    });

    const updatePublicationCardSizes = () => {
        setTitleHeight(getContainerMaxHeightByClassName('innerPubTitleDiv'));        
    };

    const getContainerMaxHeightByClassName = (innerDivClassName) => {
        var classNameList = document.getElementsByClassName(innerDivClassName);

        if (classNameList != undefined) {
            var maxHeight = 0;

            for (var index = 0; index < classNameList.length; index++) {              
                var divHeight = classNameList[index].clientHeight;

                if (maxHeight < divHeight) {
                    maxHeight = divHeight;
                }
            }

            if (maxHeight > 0) {
                return maxHeight;                
            } else {
                return '100%';                
            }
        }
    };    

    return (
        <PubContainer>
            <a href={`/publications/${props.publicationData.id}`} target="blank">              
                <div
                    style={{ height: pubTitleHeight }}>
                        <div className="innerPubTitleDiv">
                            {props.publicationData.header}                            
                            <span>
                                &nbsp;{props.publicationData.subtitle}
                            </span>       
                        </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </PubContainer>
    );
}
```

Comment: If this is a new project you're making, then it maybe worthwhile looking into using Hooks (React 16.8) there is a hook called `useLayoutEffect`, which you can easily get the highest height of the components, then update a state value in the parent, and set all children to that height.

Comment: It's an existing project that I've taken over. I'll look into hooks though and I'll have to see if I can upgrade to 16.8 without breaking anything. It still makes no sense to me why the maximize button thinks that the clientHeight is 28 instead of 85 though and thus doesn't resize it properly. If I change the browser width by dragging after a maximize or restore, it fixes the height right away.

Comment: Tomorrow I'll put something together to use this functionality then will post as answer if someone doesn't beat me to it.